# What is the music during the stripper's dance in '3 Days to Kill"?

Tags: soundtrack, 3-days-to-kill

I am trying to identify the music from the '3 Days to Kill' soundtrack during the stripper's dance. The scene is at 1:19:52 (1hr 19min and 52 seconds) into the movie.

- The music only plays briefly. I assume that's why it is not identified in the OST listing (here's one of several, it's not yet on IMDB: http://msoundtracks.blogspot.com/2014/02/3-days-to-kill-2014-full-soundtrack-ost.html)
- Shazam doesn't identify it.
- I found the full soundtrack release on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nMhp8r-01zU) but after a careful listing didn't encounter it there either.

Comment: Why the downvote? I tried to ask a specific, relevant question and spent time researching first.

Comment: The downvote may be because certain of your links answer the question (msoundtracks.blogspot.com includes "Spoutnik") or because they are outdated (the Youtube video has been taken down for copyright infringement). You might also include more description of what's happening in the scene for visual context. I agree it's a good, specific question though!

Comment: Darude - Sandstorm

Comment: :/ This was a trivial question to identify a song, not about the soundtrack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The song is "Spoutnik" by MIRWAIS.

It is listed as "Crazy Horse Paris Spoutnik" on websites unrelated and existing prior to Three Days to Kill, and at the [end of the film credits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnSZD.png) and on websites related to the film as follows:

> Music Crazy Horse : SPoUTNIK
>
> by MIRWAIS
>
> (c) TORA BORA / CRAZY HORSE PRODUCTIONS
>
> (p) CRAZY HORSE PRODUCTIONS

The song does not appear in producer Mirwais Ahmadzaï's discography.

As of this writing, "Spoutnik" is not for sale individually or as part of Three Days to Kill's [official soundtrack](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00J37WKUE), but can be streamed or downloaded [here](http://myfreemp3.eu/music/crazy+horse+paris#) along with other tracks produced by/for Parisian cabaret [Crazy Horse](http://www.lecrazyhorseparis.com/en).

Trivia:

The dancer in the film is performing a modified version of a two-person sequence from Crazy Horse circa 2012, which can be seen in Youtube trailers [here](http://youtu.be/-5xBvyXeDvw?t=1m34s) and [here](http://youtu.be/YjLgDoZedUY?t=21s) (warning: nudity). These trailers are for "FEU: Crazy Horse Paris", a theatrical version of the cabaret show which included the sequence.

A 2011 documentary about Crazy Horse (trailer [here](http://youtu.be/pfLqvgWmCb8?t=1m10s)) (warning again) details the production process for sequences and their original songs, for which dancers sometimes record their own vocals. It's likely that Mirwais was commissioned to make a song for the *sequence* called Spoutnik, incorporating vocals by one or both of the dancers. (Notice the dancer is lipsyncing in Three Days to Kill; she's performing her own song.) Where the song and the sequence are a package fully owned by Crazy Horse, until Three Days to Kill there was no need to assign further credit. Credit seems to have finally been assigned as we see in the film per the particulars of Hollywood's code of credits.

Interestingly, neither dancer gets song credit, nor does the dancer in the film get a cast credit.

Comment: Thanks for the detail and the back story. Very interesting!

Comment: @azqa: My pleasure! It was fun to research this. How and why things get credited are such a mess.

Comment: Is there any connection between the Crazy Horse package and Beyonce's similar looking dance in her music video for "Partition"?